# Overlapping polygon outlines dashed at overlapping locations but solid elsewhere

Tags: arcmap, symbology, overlapping-features

In ArcMap 10.0, if one smaller polygon fits inside of another and shares a portion of the larger polygon's boundary, and they both are set to display thick outlines on the inside, is there a way to make them dashed where they overlap so that you can see where the outlines coincide? And then just have the outlines solid everywhere else?

Comment: Not sure...what about blue lines and 70% transparent yellow lines to get green overlaps?